# Smaller number generation from a large number and total of smaller number must be a large number

Tags: php

How can I generate fix smaller random numbers from a large number.  Addition of these smaller numbers must be equal to large number. Suppose I want to generate 400 random number and addition of these smaller number = e.g. 1,000,000. every number should be unique and have any value assign to it.  Like Number 1=1000 and number 2 may contain only 5.  But total of all the number must be a large number.  Is there any algorithm to do this kind of operation in php?

Answer (score 1):

```
function array_generate_sum($n, $total)
{
    $sum = 0;
    $arr = array();
    for( ; $n >= 0; $n--)
    {
        $current = $n == 0 ? $total - $sum : mt_rand(1, $total - $sum - $n);
        $sum += $current;
        $arr[] = $current;
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

```
// Generate an array of 5 values whose sum is 30
array_generate_sum(5, 30);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.  I tried this function with parameter (400,1000000) but it do not generate random number properly.  Do I need to change anything in function?

Comment: @NareshChauhan:  Can you be more specific than it "it doesn't generate the number properly"?  Do you mean that it's not normally distributed?

Comment: Actually it generates few random numbers but when we pass above parameter it generates 1 as a random number in almost all the array keys